# Story about an alien reporting on a military operation carried out by humans

Tags: story-identification, space

This is an online story I read a few months ago but I can't find it anymore. It is about an alien envoy making a report on the subjugation of a moth-like alien race tasked to the humans.

First one of the officers in charge of the operation gives the soldiers a briefing about what their objectives are, including the fact that one of the marine companies had to be replaced by a company of the "system guards" or something like that. They would also have to insert the forces into the planet and fight without any air support in the first part of the operation.

Then the officer continues saying they'd have to improvise a way to drop tanks from orbit for that same reason but that there is good news in the form of a detachment from the fleet stopping their military exercises to go and help them.

The story continues with the planetfall in which the envoy was put into a Baby Carrier and strapped to the chest of said officer during the insertion and then narrates parts of the fight on the planet's surface.

To summarize the end, said detachment of the fleet arrives a day after the defending aliens were pushed all the way back to their last stronghold, and a single ship appears from the sky and deploys a gun that is 300 meters long, which is as large as the largest ship in the alien envoy's fleet and after loading for a few minutes it fires, producing a blinding white light also producing a shockwave that pushed the envoy back a few meters, and after he stands again and looks at where the stronghold was, there is just a giant crater.

They also mention the system guards got surrounded by enemy forces while fighting in the asteroid belt of the system the story takes place in and now need to be rescued.

I might have mixed up a few details of the story but overall that's how it goes, could you help me find it?

Comment: This sounds like something from Reddit's HFY forum.

Comment: @Valorum I agree. I also think it is mixing two HFY stories into a single one. But I can't find either one, to prove it. IIRC, they would be from 2-3 months ago.